# XPath 1.0: Substitute for using parantheses

Tags: xpath

Consider the following XML:

```
<A>
  <B />
</A>
<A>
  <B />
</A>
```

Is there a way to avoid using parantheses in this XPath 1.0 expression to get the second B element?

```
(/A/B)[2]
```

If I use /A/B[2], empty set is returned as there is no second B under any A. What I need is something that tells an XPath processor to evaluate the preceeding expression and apply a predicate to the result.

The reason I need this is that while constructing an XPath expression, I don't know the preceeding and following parts (i.e. I'm unable to place an opening paranthesis). At the moment, I only know that I want to append /B to the expression and apply a predicate to the result.

Answer (score 1):

This XML is not well formed - it should have only one root. Let's pretend there is `<R>` at the top.

You can now search for `/R/A[2]/B` to get the second B. But once you have `/R/A`, the only possible way is to enclose the whole expression in parenthesis and add `B[2]`. Why is it a problem to place the parenthesis at the very beginning?

Comment: No, it's an inner part, the whole xml is of course well formed. The way XPath expression is being constructed I'm not aware of other parts of the expression, as I've already mentioned in the question. That's why I tried looking for something else than parantheses.

Answer (score 1):

The following still uses the parenthesis, but only inside of the predicate filter, so you could append that as you are constructing your XPath:

```
/A/B[count(.|(/A/B)[2])=1]
```

It uses the [Kaysian technique](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/muench.html#d9940e108) for set difference.  The count of the union of the current node and the selection of the second `/A/B` will be 1 if the current node is the same.

Comment: If I knew the previous parts of the expression, I'd be able to use parantheses as a simpler solution..

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
    //A/B[@id='2']
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly there is no such id in the real document. I've used it here for easily identifying the element I need to pick.